# Why does my HQL ignore Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hql

I have this code:

```
IList<Foo1> ou = session.CreateQuery("from Foo1 as f1 JOIN FETCH f1.foo2 as f2 USING (id_foo1) where f2.foo3.year ='2004'").List<Foo1>();
```

It returns all objects from Foo1 and ignores where clause. Why? Where is probably mistake?

Next experiments:

```
 (1) from Foo2 as f2 where f2.year = '2004'  //is OK
 (2) from Foo1 as f1 JOIN FETCH f1.foo2 as f2 USING (id_foo1)  //is OK
 (3) from Foo1 as f1 JOIN FETCH f1.foo2 as f2 USING (id_foo1) where f2.year = '2004'  //returns the same result as (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it is little bit confusing for me as well, but in one example I found this note: "You don't need the WHERE clause as Hibernate "knows" how to match primary and foreign keys based on the mapping." This "Where" was related to JOIN condition so just try to remove your USING() part.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use SQL profiler to see whether the SQL that gets sent to the server is correct.
2. Simplify the query until it works. Then work backwards to find the error. Remove the join fetch to see if it changes something.

Comment: our result:  (1) from Foo2 as f2 where f2.year = '2004'  .. is OK                    
 (2) from Foo1 as f1 JOIN FETCH f1.foo2 as f2 USING (id_foo1)  .. is OK                                             
 (3) from Foo1 as f+ JOIN FETCH f1.foo2 as f2 USING (id_foo1) where f2.year = '2004'  .. returns the same result as (2)

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL for 2 and 3? What about "from Foo1 as f1 where f1.foo2.year = '2004'"?

Comment: I can't do this, because foo2 is List<Foo2> in Foo1 class. And sorry but i don't know how to get generated sql...

Comment: Run SQL profiler from your startmenu. Connect to the SQL Server. You will see your queries running through immediately.